# How do I filter a listbox based on selected date in Userform VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am working on Userforms in VBA for the first time. I have a calendar userform from which I select a date which is displayed on a textbox. By default the textbox shows the current day. At the bottom I have a listbox. I want to filter the data in the listbox based on the current date/date selected by the user.

I am doing this but it does produce any result in the listbox. Do I need to convert the date into some other type?

```
Sub Attendance_Display_Listbox()
    Dim dsh As Worksheet
    Set dsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Attendance")
     
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AttendanceDisplay")
    
     '''Filter data datewise
    dsh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 5, "=" & Me.txt_Date.Value
    
    sh.Cells.ClearContents
    dsh.UsedRange.Copy
    sh.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    sh.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    dsh.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim last_row As Long
    last_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))
    If last_row = 1 Then last_row = 2
    
    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ColumnCount = 8
        .ColumnWidths = "0,50,200,150,70,50,100,70" '0 for not displaying the Serial no
        .RowSource = sh.Name & "!A2:H" & last_row
    End With
End Sub
```

For a different date selected then -

```
Private Sub txt_Date_Change()
Call Attendance_Display_Listbox
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim dsh As Worksheet
    Set dsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Attendance")
     
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AttendanceDisplay")
    
    dsh.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    dsh.Range("E:E").NumberFormat = "D-MMM-YYYY"
    
    '''filter
    dsh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 5, "=" & Me.txt_Date.Value
    
    sh.UsedRange.Clear
    dsh.UsedRange.Copy
    sh.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    dsh.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim last_row As Long
    last_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))
    If last_row = 1 Then last_row = 2
    
    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ColumnCount = 8
        .ColumnWidths = "0,50,200,150,70,50,100,70" '0 for not displaying the Serial no
        .RowSource = sh.Name & "!A2:H" & last_row
    End With
 
End Sub
```

This works!